# nodejs async loop with delay

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a loop working with a longer delay, when the task takes longer as planned.

currently I'm using this code for the loop:

```
async function doSomeStuff() {
    // do some stuff
    // sometimes this action may take longer than 5 seconds
    // after finishing wait 5 seconds
    console.log('task completed, waiting 5 seconds for next run...');
}

setInterval(doSomeStuff, 5000);
```

works like a charm, but the delay is fixed at 5 seconds, even if the tasks takes longer as planned, so that sometimes the new loop starts only 1 second after finishing the last one instead of waiting 5 seconds.

unfortunately, I was not able to solve it myself by looking at the other questions.

I am grateful for any help.

Best regards
Paedda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`async` functions shouldn't be used with API that ignores a promise that it returns such as `setInterval`, in case it's expected that a promise should be chained.

This can be done with recursive `async` function:

```
(async function doSomeStuff() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    // do some stuff
    await doSomeStuff();
})();
```

Or infinite loop:

```
(async function doSomeStuff() {
    while (true) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
        // do some stuff
    }
})();
```

Function body can be wrapped with `try..catch` if needed to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there

```
async function doSomeStuff() {
    // do some stuff
    // sometimes this action may take longer than 5 seconds
    // after finishing wait 5 seconds
    console.log('task completed, waiting 5 seconds for next run...');
    setTimeout(doSomeStuff, 5000);
}
```